# angular material - change input underline color after input is submitted

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to change the color of mat-input-underline :
first :  the line is grey and its ok
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja2QM.png)

second : on focus the line is purple and its ok
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMOFf.png)

at the end the underline color return to be black after focus on other field.

i want that after focus the color will remain purple.

how do i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For each mat input: on focus gain, set a boolean hadFocus to true. Use a [class.had-focus]="hadFocus" directive on your mat input element and apply the "purple" styles in your CSS to the .had-focus class.

You might think you can do that using a form control's pristine field. But if I remember correctly, the pristine field will reset automatically at some point. You can give it a try though.

Comment: can i change it in my theme.css?

Comment: since this is angular material, my guess is that you can't change it in the view-encapsulated component css, so you'd have to do it in a file that eventually gets imported into your global styles (styles.scss if you're using SCSS) or directly into styles.scss. Also, you might have to use ng deep or important. Angular material is weird like that sometimes.